# How find the LTE bandwidth in Android

Tags: android, bandwidth, telephonymanager, lte

I need to find the LTE bandwidth in Android. I tried requestCellInfoUpdate method in TelephonyManager:

```
cellInfoCallbackObject = MyCellInfoCallback()
executor = requireActivity().mainExecutor
tm.requestCellInfoUpdate(executor, cellInfoCallbackObject)


class MyCellInfoCallback( ) : TelephonyManager.CellInfoCallback() {
     override fun onCellInfo(cellInfoList: MutableList<CellInfo>) {
             for (cellInfo in cellInfoList) {
                 if ((cellInfo is CellInfoLte) && cellInfo.isRegistered) {
                    val bandwidth =cellInfo.cellIdentity.bandwidth.toString()
              }
}}}
```

But it returns an invalid value. Can anyone help me?

Edit: The invalid value is 2147483647. I tested on "Samsung SMA-336E" and " Xiaomi M2003j15SC" with Android 12. In Iran country and IR-MCI operator.
Some other applications such as G-NetTrack Lite, show the bandwidth on these phones correctly.

Comment: The invalid value is 2147483647. I tested on "Samsung SMA-336E" and " Xiaomi M2003j15SC" with Android 12. In Iran and IR-MCI operator

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/CellIdentityLte#getBandwidth()) 2147483647 means [UNAVAILABLE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/CellInfo#UNAVAILABLE). So the phone and/or the cell tower does not provide this information, or at least not through this API.

Comment: But some other applications such as G-NetTrack Lite, show the bandwidth on these phones correctly. How they obtain bandwidth?

Comment: Those apps may use a different API.

Comment: can you help me more?